# Wrong values received by MQL5 iCustom function

Tags: mql4, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to call the MQL4 indicator with MQL5 using `iCustom()` .

```
int test = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"ADXmagic.ex4");
```

I have copies  the two buffers with number 0 and  in the a and b of double type.

```
CopyBuffer(test,0,0,5,a);
   CopyBuffer(test,1,0,5,b);
   ArrayPrint(a);
   ArrayPrint(b);
```

But the output  received is completely garbage and no values:

```
 6E+39    2E+92  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
4E+230  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
 6E+39    2E+92  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
4E+230  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
 6E+39    2E+92  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
4E+230  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
 6E+39    2E+92  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
4E+230  0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000 +0.00000
```

Kindly, let me know am I correct on calling the indicator? Is there a flaw I made?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call ex4 files from MT5 I am afraid. And it is a bad idea even if that could be possible because MT5 indicators work faster then MT4 indicators.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find ADXmagic indicator for MT5? If there isn't for MT5 then tell me how to use MT4 indicator in MT5?

Comment: It is not possible to use MT4 indicators in MT5 I believe. How can I tell you where you can find some indicator? probably at the same place where you found MT4 indicator. This is a programmers forum, not database of indicators

Comment: I do not mean to offend you sir. The thing is, I am expecting to have a solution by hook or crook. If you are answering in denial of the usage then what else I could do , is what I am expecting in the answer.Anyone could have given this answer to me. But I am expecting that the elite programmers here, should help me instead of saying directly NO.

Comment: If this is truely a programmer forum then why always I get certain one line answers instead of the solution? This might mean that people here are not interested in helping. Just trying to get rid of the question by writing the known facts instead of giving a concrete solution.

Comment: there are many decisions: compare your ADX with default and decide that the custom one is of no use; compare the ADX's and see what might be the difference and update your mq5 ADX indicator; google source of your mt4 indicator and rewrite it to mt5. And there is one way that wont work: calling MT4 indicator from MT5. Your question looks similar to "where I can find source codes of Windows?" - and the reply is similar. You MCVE and recieved a reply that it is not possible because languages are different. If you accepted all the answers you got, some elite programmers might help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply..... But my question was not "where I can find source codes of Windows?" or even near by. I have asked the question in comment after your answer. Else my question was still the same "Wrong values received by MQL5 iCustom function
". Anyways Thank you for your reply answer.